# Hide sort arrow after change header label

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use JTable, and here how it's like when I use

[image]

As you can see it's show sort arrow. Nice. Now I want to change color of header when filter by this column. I use this code:

```
private void refreshColumnHeader() {
        // model column "Added on" index always = 2
        JLabel blueLabel = new JLabel(m2DocumentsTableModel.getColumnName(modelColumnIndex), JLabel.CENTER);
        blueLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        blueLabel.setBorder(headerBorder);
        TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new JComponentTableCellRenderer();
        TableColumnModel columnModel = m2DocumentsTableView.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn columnAddedOn = columnModel.getColumn(vColIndex);
        if (modelColumnIndex == 1) { // column "Added On"
            if (!dateTimeFilter.hasFilter()) {
                blueLabel.setForeground(foregroundTableHeaderNotFilter);
            } else {
                blueLabel.setForeground(foregroundTableHeaderFilter);
            }
        }
        columnAddedOn.setHeaderRenderer(tableCellRenderer);
        columnAddedOn.setHeaderValue(blueLabel);
    }
```

But now the arrow is hide.

[image]

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: java doc setHeaderRenderer: _It is the header renderers responsibility to render the sorting indicator. If you are using sorting and specify a renderer your renderer must render the sorting indication._

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by implementing a custom `TableCellRenderer`. In particular it would be useful to reuse the default header renderer (because of the sort icons, colors and label) by wrapping it in the custom `TableCellRenderer` and just modifying it with the desired foreground color when sorting on that column is detected:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class SortedRowHeaderRendererDemo {
    
    private static class SortedRowHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        
        private final TableCellRenderer originalRenderer;
        private Color originalForeground;
        
        public SortedRowHeaderRenderer(final TableCellRenderer originalRenderer) {
            this.originalRenderer = Objects.requireNonNull(originalRenderer);
            originalForeground = null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table,
                                                       final Object value,
                                                       final boolean isSelected,
                                                       final boolean hasFocus,
                                                       final int row,
                                                       final int column) {
            final Component original = originalRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            
            if (row < 0 && original instanceof JComponent) {
                final JComponent originalJComponent = (JComponent) original;
                if (originalForeground == null)
                    originalForeground = originalJComponent.getForeground();
                Color fg = originalForeground;
                final RowSorter<?> sorter = table.getRowSorter();
                if (sorter instanceof DefaultRowSorter) {
                    final List<? extends SortKey> keys = sorter.getSortKeys();
                    if (!keys.isEmpty()) {
                        final SortKey k = keys.get(0); /*The first key is the most
                        significant one for sorting, ie the last selected sorting column.*/
                        if (k.getColumn() == table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column)) {
                            final SortOrder order = k.getSortOrder();
                            if (SortOrder.ASCENDING.equals(order))
                                fg = Color.RED;
                            else if (SortOrder.DESCENDING.equals(order))
                                fg = Color.GREEN;
                            //Don't forget here that there are also 'SortOrder.UNSORTED' and 'null' values for 'order'!
                        }
                    }
                }
                originalJComponent.setForeground(fg);
            }
            
            return original;
        }
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        
        final String addedOnColumn = "Added on";
        
        final JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] {
            new Object[]{"Data001", "Data002", "Data003"},
            new Object[]{"Data011", "Data012", "Data013"},
            new Object[]{"Data021", "Data022", "Data023"},
            new Object[]{"Data031", "Data032", "Data033"},
            new Object[]{"Data041", "Data042", "Data043"}
        }, new Object[] {"Column1", "Column2", addedOnColumn});
        
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        final TableColumn col = table.getColumn(addedOnColumn);
        col.setHeaderRenderer(new SortedRowHeaderRenderer(table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()));
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table renderer demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SortedRowHeaderRendererDemo::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

#### Features:

A feature (or bug fix rather) is that the code works for tables with column reordering enabled too.

#### Limitations:

1. The wrapped `TableCellRenderer` must return a `JComponent` in order to set its foreground property, which should be the color of the text. For example `TableCellRenderer`s which return `JLabel`s are supported (such as `DefaultTableCellRenderer`s). This seems to be the case though, if pre-installed or default renderers are used.
2. The `RowSorter` of the table must be of type `DefaultRowSorter` (such as a `TableRowSorter`) in order to determine if the column is sorted and what is its sort order. That's because the `RowSorter` class does not make any guarantees as far as I checked for the order of `SortKey`s returned by its `getSortKeys` method. On the other hand `DefaultRowSorter` guarantees that "*Sorting is done based on the current SortKeys, **in order***" (I am assuming the order in which the `SortKey`s are returned by the method `getSortKeys` is implied here). By default the `JTable` though seems to create a `DefaultRowSorter` already.